Is there overhead introduced by manually loading assemblies during runtime?
Without any intervention, the default behavior of a .net application is looking in the same directory where it's run to locate assemblies (.dll's).
I like it when my build folder is not loaded with 200 files, so I decided to move them to a subfolder called 'libs'.
Here's how I move them POST build:
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

IF NOT EXIST "$(OutputPath)libs" mkdir "$(OutputPath)libs"

for %%F in ("$(OutputPath)*.*") do (
    set "filename=%%~nxF"
    
    if /I NOT "!filename!"=="$(TargetName).exe" (
    if /I NOT "!filename!"=="$(TargetName).dll" (
    if /I NOT "!filename!"=="$(TargetName).pdb" (
    if /I NOT "!filename!"=="$(TargetName).dll.config" (
    if /I NOT "!filename!"=="$(TargetName).deps.json" (
    if /I NOT "!filename!"=="$(TargetName).runtimeconfig.json" (
        move "%%F" "$(OutputPath)libs"
    ))))))
)

Then in the static constructor of Program, I load the assemblies manually using Reflection:
 const string LIB_FOLDER = "libs";
 const string ASS_EXT = ".dll";

 static Program()
 {
     AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
 }

 private static Assembly? OnAssemblyResolve(object? sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
 {
     AssemblyName assemblyName = new(args.Name);
     string assemblyNameStr = assemblyName.Name + ASS_EXT;
     string assemblyPath = Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, LIB_FOLDER, assemblyNameStr);

     if (File.Exists(assemblyPath))
     {
         return Assembly.LoadFrom(assemblyPath);
     }

     return null;
 }

Will loading assemblies manually like this introduce overhead?
Should I abandon the dream of making the build folder clean by letting all the DLL's stay where they're generated?

If keeping your build folder clean is your only motivation I wouldn't do this. It's just going to introduce complexity in your application with no benefit. If you had to handle something more specific like loading multiple versions of the same assembly, handling some specific errors then maybe

@jitter Of course this isn't something that should be done in any projects, but I'd rather have the build folder as clean as possible. So I use it on small individual projects.

A valid reason for doing this is to dynamically load Add-Ins.

Anecdotally, for some of our utilities that I wrote, I use OnAssemblyResolve to load assemblies, not from a separate directory, but rather from resources, and I've not noticed any performance difference from the default mode.

Can't you just set the PrivateBinPath or ApplicationBase and let the framework do the loading/binding? I don't think what you're doing will make any appreciable difference to performance, but I've seen difficult to diagnose run-time errors from people rolling their own assembly loading.

@iakobski AppDomainSetup.ApplicationBase is read only. AppDomainSetup.PrivateBinPath exists in .net framework only (1.1 - 4.8.1 as of today). ApplicationDomainSetup does not have a public constructor.

Thanks @Quidney I did not realise that. The fact this is not available since .net core is probably a signal that doing this sort of thing is not recommended. As it's for small individual projects there's probably no real harm, and to answer your original question the overhead will be minimal since it's not much different to what happens under the hood anyway.
